# MySQL COUNT query with or without HAVING clause giving same results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issues with an SQL query which involves a COUNT and a HAVING clause. 
The objective is to get the count of all products that have stock and are also not being 'picked' for another customer hence the HAVING clause.

However, when the query is run both with and without the HAVING clause at the end of the query below I get the same COUNT as the result.

To ensure that the COUNT results should not be the same I tried running queries to check if there were products that were out of stock since all products will need to be in stock for the results to match up and confirmed that there were definitely products out of stock.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_variant pv
  ON pv.product_variant_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN depot_product_stock dps
  ON dps.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
            FROM `picklist_item` pii
            WHERE pii.STATUS IN ('not picked')
  ) AS pickListNotPicked
  ON pickListNotPicked.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
            FROM `picklist_item` pii
            LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
            WHERE pii.STATUS IN ('picked')
            AND pii.date_picked > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
            AND packi.picklist_id IS NULL
  ) AS pickListPicked
  ON pickListPicked.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
            FROM `picklist_item` pii
            LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
            WHERE packi.`status` IN ('new', 'in progress')
  ) AS pickListInProgress
  ON pickListInProgress.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
WHERE p.deleted = 0
HAVING SUM(dps.physical_stock)
    - ifnull(SUM(pickListNotPicked.quantity),0)
    - ifnull(SUM(pickListPicked.quantity) ,0)
    - ifnull(SUM(pickListInProgress.quantity) ,0)
    > 0
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong with the query. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: If you start normalising this extremely suboptimal query, sure you'll find the problem cause...

Comment: Tried several times. As Gordon said the having clause must have been redundant in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a `having` clause.  Your query is just returning one row.  That `having` clause might have it return zero rows instead of 1 row.  And, the `having` clause is looking over all the products.

Perhaps you want a `where` clause instead:

```
WHERE p.deleted = 0 AND
      (dps.physical_stock - ifnull(pickListNotPicked.quantity, 0) -
       ifnull(pickListPicked.quantity, 0)
       ifnull(pickListInProgress.quantity, 0)
      ) > 0
```

Note that I prefer replacing `ifnull()` with `coalesce()`.  (When given the option, I generally prefer the ANSI standard functions.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the quick reply. When I used coalesce however I got a "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range". I therefore had to edit coalesce(pickListPicked.quantity, 0) to coalesce(pickListPicked.quantity / -1, 0). Worked a charm! Thanks mate!

Comment: I switched the answer back to `ifnull()`.  I thought they were basically equivalent but they seem to handle types differently.

Comment: Oh ok. Switched back to ifnull(). Coalesce was working but must have been returning the wrong count. Awesome! Cheers for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are mixing up all the quantities to check.

Your query appears to be trying to find a count of products where the physical stock quantity is not equal the the sum of the quantities in various status'.

The trouble is that you are SUMing up all the stock quanties and pick quantities for ALL products. Thus if any single product has a mismatch it will be reflected in the check in the HAVING clause.

I think you need one large sub query to get all the product ids where the quantities do not match, and then do a count based on that.

Something like this (untested).

```
SELECT COUNT(product_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT p.product_id
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_variant pv
    ON pv.product_variant_id = p.product_id
    LEFT JOIN depot_product_stock dps
    ON dps.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
        FROM `picklist_item` pii
        WHERE pii.STATUS IN ('not picked')
    ) AS pickListNotPicked
    ON pickListNotPicked.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
        FROM `picklist_item` pii
        LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
        WHERE pii.STATUS IN ('picked')
        AND pii.date_picked > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
        AND packi.picklist_id IS NULL
    ) AS pickListPicked
    ON pickListPicked.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pii.quantity, pii.product_variant_id
        FROM `picklist_item` pii
        LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
        WHERE packi.`status` IN ('new', 'in progress')
    ) AS pickListInProgress
    ON pickListInProgress.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    WHERE p.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING SUM(dps.physical_stock)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListNotPicked.quantity),0)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListPicked.quantity) ,0)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListInProgress.quantity) ,0)
        > 0
) sub0
```

You might be able to remove some of the sub queries you already have like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT p.product_id
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_variant pv
      ON pv.product_variant_id = p.product_id
    LEFT JOIN depot_product_stock dps
      ON dps.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pii.product_variant_id,
                SUM(IF(pii.STATUS IN ('not picked')), quantity, 0) AS pickListNotPicked_qty,
                SUM(IF(pii.STATUS IN ('picked') AND pii.date_picked > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND packi.picklist_id IS NULL), quantity, 0) AS pickListPicked_qty,
                SUM(IF(packi.`status` IN ('new', 'in progress')), quantity, 0) AS pickListInProgress_qty
        FROM `picklist_item` pii
        LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
        GROUP BY pii.product_variant_id
    ) AS quantities
    ON quantities.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    WHERE p.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING SUM(dps.physical_stock)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListNotPicked_qty),0)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListPicked_qty) ,0)
        - IFNULL(SUM(pickListInProgress_qty) ,0)
) sub0
```

This might be further cleaned down to :-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT p.product_id
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_variant pv
      ON pv.product_variant_id = p.product_id
    LEFT JOIN depot_product_stock dps
      ON dps.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pii.product_variant_id,
                SUM(quantities) AS relevant_qty
        FROM `picklist_item` pii
        LEFT JOIN `packing` packi ON packi.picklist_id = pii.picklist_id
        WHERE pii.STATUS  = 'not picked'
        OR (pii.STATUS = 'picked' AND pii.date_picked > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND packi.picklist_id IS NULL)
        OR packi.`status` IN ('new', 'in progress')
        GROUP BY pii.product_variant_id
    ) AS quantities
    ON quantities.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
    WHERE p.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING SUM(dps.physical_stock)
        - IFNULL(SUM(relevant_qty) ,0)
) sub0
```

Note that I am slightly unsure of your sum logic if I understand your requirement correctly. You could items that are not picked and items picked in the last week. You also count items that have a status of new or in progress, yet it would seem these items could already have been counted as picked / not picked, hence double counted for the sums and ensuring that the final sums did not match and the items were used for the count of product ids.

Comment: Hi Kickstart, I implemented the last query you wrote out and is a lot more efficient than what I started with. Sql profiling showed that your query was also over a second quicker. I just made a few minor edits to make it work. Thanks mate.